# Automatic use of large numbers of combinations of parameters as input for a function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to simulate large numbers of distributions in R in the sense that I'm generating quantiles for different parameters of distributions. I want to create a dataset with a large number of combinations of these parameters. For example (using the normal distribution):

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(ncol=104,nrow=2))
colnames(df)<-c(as.character(seq(0,1,0.01),"type","mean","sd"))
```

Which gives me a dataframe with 101 columns for the quantiles from 0 to 1 in 0.01 steps and three additional columns for "type", "mean" and "sd" (which are the only parameters when using a normal distribution).

Now let's generate the quantiles for two members out of the normal distribution family:

```
qnorm.0.1<-qnorm(seq(0,1,0.01),0,1) #normal distribution / mean=0 /sd=1
qnorm.0.2<-qnorm(seq(0,1,0.01),0,2) #normal distribution / mean=0 /sd=2
```

Now I'm able to fill my dataframe with the two vectors:

```
df[1,]<-c(qnorm.0.1,"normal","0","1")
df[2,]<-c(qnorm.0.2,"normal","0","2")
```

Which gives me the format that I need. 
However, as I'm trying to create large datasets with many combinations of the parameters (for example every combination for a mean from 1 to 10000 and sd from 1 to 10000) I will have to come up with a way of automatising this process. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you post your code showing what you want to do with small numbers of combinations of parameters.

Comment: are you looking for `?expand.grid`?

Comment: Well, for my example you could use a for-loop, for example:

`for (i in 1:2) {
  df[i,]<-c(qnorm(seq(0,1,0.01),0,i),"normal","0",i)
}`

However, I suppose using for-loops with more than 1 layer and for large numbers will make the code very slow, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ben Bolker: Thanks for that, that's already helping. expand.grid allows me to keep the for loop in one layer:

`comb<-expand.grid(c(0:1),c(1:2))

for (i in 1:4){
  df[i,]<-c(qnorm(seq(0,1,0.01),comb$Var1[i],comb$Var2[i]),"normal",comb$Var1[i],comb$Var2[i])
}`

However, is there a way to do it more efficiently (i.e. without for-loops)?

Comment: I was thinking, is combinations of parameters what you need, or permutations? Because combinations will lead for instance to 1 mean, 2 sd, but not the other way around, I think you need permutations isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help,

```
library(data.table)
## Generate Parameters
param <- 0:9
## Generate Combinatios of par.
cb <- combn(par,2, simplify = F)
n <- length(cb)
## Input the parameters
DT <- lapply(cb, function(x){data.table(rbind(qnorm(seq(0, 1, 0.01),x)))})
DT <- rbindlist(DT)
DT[, `:=`(type=rep("normal",n),
          mean = unlist(cb)[seq(1, n*2, 2) ],
          sd = unlist(cb)[seq(2, n*2, 2) ])]
## Change names
setnames(DT, c(paste0("qnorm", seq(0, 1, 0.01)), "type", "mean", "sd"))
dim(DT)
[1]  45 104

head(DT[,95:104])
   qnorm0.94 qnorm0.95 qnorm0.96 qnorm0.97 qnorm0.98 qnorm0.99 qnorm1   type mean sd
1:  1.554774  2.644854  1.750686  2.880794  2.053749  3.326348    Inf normal    0  1
2:  1.554774  3.644854  1.750686  3.880794  2.053749  4.326348    Inf normal    0  2
3:  1.554774  4.644854  1.750686  4.880794  2.053749  5.326348    Inf normal    0  3
4:  1.554774  5.644854  1.750686  5.880794  2.053749  6.326348    Inf normal    0  4
5:  1.554774  6.644854  1.750686  6.880794  2.053749  7.326348    Inf normal    0  5
6:  1.554774  7.644854  1.750686  7.880794  2.053749  8.326348    Inf normal    0  6
```

You can, of course, increase the number of parameters or change the distribution function, but the outcome will be similar.

Comment: Thanks, it's a nice starting point. Unfortunately other distributions (e.g. qpareto() ) won't take the list argument, but I'm sure I'll find a workaround for that :)

Comment: I don't think you'll have a problem with that because `lapply` is taking each element of the list, and in this case they are vectors. But, perhaps you can give me an example.

Comment: You can just try to use your code with `qpareto()` from the rmutil package instead of `qnorm()` and it will tell you, that one parameter is missing, which I find interesting, as both distributions will take two parameters. However, you can do a workaround using `mapply()` like this:


`var<-cb
var1<-lapply(var, "[", c(1))
var2<-lapply(var, "[", c(2))


DT<-data.table(rbind(mapply(function(X,Y) {qpareto(seq(0,1,0.01),X,Y)}, X=var1, Y=var2)))`

Comment: You don't really need mapply, it is slower than lapply. Check this, generate the combination of parameters as a list `cb <- combn(1:5, 2, simplify = F)`; then create an empty list with the same length `out <- vector("list", length(cb))`; pass the parameters as a function using lapply, and split them inside of the `qpareto`; `out <- lapply(cb, function(x){data.table(rbind(qpareto(seq(0,1,0.01), x[1], x[2])))})`